# Rubyの仮引数が*だけの意味とは？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsの中身を読んでいました

```
def sum(*)
  calculate :sum, nil
end
```

仮引数が `*` のみです。
何を示していてどういうときに使うのでしょうか？

---

追記：
cul8erさんの回答によって、一般的に子クラスの`initialize`で使うことがわかりました。

> 何に使うことが多いかというと、多分、基底クラスの#initialzeにsuperで引数渡しをする際に、派生クラス側で親の#initializeの引数数を把握したくない(≒依存したくない)という場合などが考えられます。

railsの`sum`のケースですと`super`と関係がないと思いますので、できればrailsの`sum`で使われている用法もお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[リファレンスマニュアル](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/spec=2fdef.html#method)に説明も用例も載っています。

> 仮引数の直前に * がある場合には残りの実引数 (後述の post 引数を除く) はみな配列とし てこの引数に格納されます。
>   可変長引数、rest 引数などと呼ばれる機能です。 このような引数は 1 つしか作れません。
>
> 例:
>
> ```
> def foo(x, *xs)
>   puts "#{x} : #{xs.inspect}"   # Object#inspect は p のような詳細な内部表示
> end
> foo(1)        #=> 1 : []
> foo(1, 2)     #=> 1 : [2]
> foo(1, 2, 3)  #=> 1 : [2, 3]
>
> def bar(x, *) # 残りの引数を単に無視したいとき
>   puts "#{x}"
> end
> bar(1)        #=> 1
> bar(1, 2)     #=> 1
> bar(1, 2, 3)  #=> 1
> ```

**残りの引数を単に無視したいとき**と書いてあるとおりでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど。残りの引数を単に無視する。つまり`sum`の場合は全部無視するということですね。

Answer (score 2):

これは確か`splat`演算子と呼ばれるものです。

```
def abc(*arg)
  arg.each{|n| p n}
end

abc(1,2,3)  #=> 1 2 3 が出力
```

このように仮引数名をつけても使えますが、実は省略可能です。
何に使うことが多いかというと、多分、基底クラスの`#initialze`に`super`で引数渡しをする際に、派生クラス側で親の`#initialize`の引数数を把握したくない(≒依存したくない)という場合などが考えられます。

例を挙げているページがあったのでご参考まで：[ここまで出来る！RubyのSplat Operatorまとめ](http://alpaca.tc/blog/ruby/how-to-use-star.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。

[引数があるスーパークラスのメソッドを呼び出す - クラスの継承 - Ruby入門](http://www.rubylife.jp/ini/inherit/index4.html)
 
（引用：引数を指定せずに「super」メソッドを呼び出した場合にはサブクラスを呼び出した時に渡されてきた引数を付けて呼び出したものと同じことになります）

引用にあるとおり、superの引数も省略できるので、子クラスのinitializeの仮引数も名前をつけないで`*`だけにして省略しちゃおう的な発想ですね。

そうなってくると、 railsのsumはなんで`*`のみを使ってるのかが気になってきてしまいました..

Comment: ご回答によって知りたいことが増えましたので、質問を編集させていただきました。